# PHP - Add Item to array within loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using a PHP framework `CodeIgniter` to throw together a quick project. I am running into a PHP related issue with one of my loops/arrays and I am looking for a push in the right direction.

**PHP Database Call:**

```
public function get_feed_data()
    {
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT c.id, c.name, c.age, c.photoName, c.photoNameSmall, c.panelColor , IFNULL(SUM(t.points), '.MAX_POINTS.') as totalPoints
                                    FROM children as c 
                                    LEFT JOIN behaviorRatings as r
                                    ON c.id = r.childID
                                    LEFT JOIN behaviorTypes as t
                                    ON r.behaviorID = t.behaviorTypeID
                                    GROUP BY c.id');
            return $query->result();
    }
```

**My Controller:**

```
    $feedData   =   $this->display_model->get_feed_data();
    $output = array();

    foreach($feedData as $d)
    {
        $rating = $this->_current_behavior($d->totalPoints[0]);
        $d['rating'] = $rating;
        $output[] = $d;
    }

    $response              = array();
    $response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
    $response['children']  = $output;
    echo json_encode($response);
```

**The Issue:**

The database call returns multiple records of data from the tables without any issues. However, I am trying to add another key/value pair to that array that is calculated through another function.

In the array, I am trying to add the key `rating` with the value of `$rating`.

The error I am getting is `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.
I assumed that `$feedData` was an `array` that I could have just pushed this value into but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: change `$d['rating'] = $rating;` to `$d->rating = $rating`. as the error suggests, the array `$feedData` actually a bunch of `stdClass` not another array, so you only need to use it as object. luckily, `php` is such a *nice* language, it lets you  to add object properties on a whim.

Comment: @SBB did you check the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that probably the `$d` variable is `stdClass` (and not `Array`) and therefore you can't use `$d[..]` on that object, because this syntax is for Array access, and not Objects.

The syntax to access Object's members is `->`:

```
$d->rating = $rating;
```

So your complete loop will look like:

```
foreach($feedData as $d)
{
    $rating = $this->_current_behavior($d->totalPoints[0]);
    $d->rating = $rating;
    $output[] = $d;
}
```